# redirect to another url using $location.path

Tags: angularjs

I have to redirect to new url from my actual webpage,
I get url from my response from backend.

```
var url = res.response.data.link;
$location.url(url);
```

but my url appends with my local host url , how to avoid this

```
http://127.0.0.1:50966/index.html#/https://www.paypal.com
```

Comment: Use window.open(url) or window.location.href = url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$window` rather than `window`, also make sure you are injecting `$window` in the `controller` as well.

```
$window.location.href = url;
```